# Copy cells "n" number of times. "n" is user specified

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to code a macro that will look at the numerical user input in one sheet and will copy something that number of times in another sheet.

For example, I want to copy the company name and ID "n" times. "n" is specified in the last column in the same row.

### Sheet1

```
company name | company ID | number of items purchased here
----------------------------------------------
blue company |  999       | 2
rose company |  444       | 1
gold company |  222       | 3
```

### Sheet 2

```
company name | company ID
---------------------------
blue company | 999
blue company | 999
rose company | 444
gold company | 222
gold company | 222
gold company | 222
```

this code does something similar but the range selected for hoe many times to copy something is always set to whatever is in "C2".

```
Sub rangecopy()
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim intHowmany As Integer

    Set source = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destination = Sheets("Sheet3")
    n = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c2") 'number of times to be copied

    Range("a2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, (Selection.Offset(0, 1))).Select

    Selection.Copy

    intHowmany = Selection.Rows.Count

    destination.Select
    Range("a2").Select

    For i = 1 To n
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(intHowmany, 0).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant but works ok and able to be changed easy enough.

```
Sub rangecopy()
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim intHowmany As Integer

    Set source = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2")
    destination.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Company"
    destination.Cells(1, 2).Value = "ID"
    startRow = 2
    usedRowsSrc = source.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = startRow To usedRowsSrc
      strCompany = source.Cells(i, 1).Value
      strID = source.Cells(i, 2).Value
      iTimes = source.Cells(i, 3).Value

      For j = 1 To iTimes
        usedRowsDest = destination.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With destination
          .Cells(usedRowsDest + 1, 1).Value = strCompany
          .Cells(usedRowsDest + 1, 2).Value = strID
        End With
      Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In my actual worksheet I have the headers in B8, C8 and the times header in F8.      So I made the start row= 9 and changed the code to`For i = startRow To usedRowsSrc
      strCompany = source.Cells(i, 2).Value
      strID = source.Cells(i, 3).Value
      iTimes = source.Cells(i, 6).Value` But doing this made the macro not do what it is supposed to. it does not put anything on Sheet 2 other than the header names

Comment: You could manually assign the value to usedRowsSrc.
Or a click the last row type dealio - usedRowSrc = Application.InputBox("Select the last row of your input data", Type:=8).Row

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quickly using arrays

This assumes your headers are in row 1, data in columns A:C

```
Sub Update()
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt2 As Long
Dim lngCnt3 As Long

Set ws = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

X = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To Application.Sum(ws.Range("B:B")) + 1)

Y(1, 1) = X(1, 1)
Y(2, 1) = X(1, 2)

lngCnt3 = 1

For lngCnt = 2 To UBound(X, 1)
    For lngCnt2 = 1 To X(lngCnt, 2)
        lngCnt3 = lngCnt3 + 1
        Y(1, lngCnt3) = X(lngCnt, 1)
        Y(2, lngCnt3) = X(lngCnt, 2)
    Next
Next

ws2.[a1].Resize(UBound(Y, 2), UBound(Y, 1)) = Application.Transpose(Y)

End Sub
```

Comment: In my actual worksheet I have the headers in B8, C8 and the times header in F8. I changed the "C" to an "F". How can I change the rest to fit where my actual information is located? I messed with it and could not get it do work for these locations